# C# - Drag item out of listview into a trash can?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

How do I drag a item out of a Winforms-listview control onto another control (picture of trash can)?

**UPDATE1:**

I think the basic flow is:

- for the ItemDrag event on the listview have a DoDragDrop
- Then have a DragEnter event on the picturebox that captures that drag?

**UPDATE2:**

The basic flow (based on answers):

- add 'ItemDrag' event to the listview.
- add a 'DoDragDrop' inside the 'ItemDrag'
- add 'DragEnter' event to the picturebox.
- add a 'GetDataPresent' check inside the 'DragEnter' to check on the data type
- add a 'DragDrop' event to the picturebox
- add a 'GetDataPresent' check inside the 'DragEnter' to check on the data type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement an event handler for the list view's ItemDrag event:

```
    private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e) {
        DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

And write the event handlers for the trash can:

```
    private void trashCan_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem))) {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
        // others...
    }

    private void trashCan_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem))) {
            var item = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)) as ListViewItem;
            item.ListView.Items.Remove(item);
        }
        // others...
    }
```

You'll have to force the AllowDrop property for the PictureBox, it isn't available in the Properties window:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        trashCan.AllowDrop = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Hans!  The samples really helped to get me on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

> **EDIT** This applies only if you want shell integrated drag-and-drop.  If you are not integrating with the shell, and only dragging and dropping between things in your own app, then this answer does not apply.  My apologies for the confusion.

---

You need to support drag-n-drop in your app or control.  This involves some COM interop.

It seems a little complicated at first, but once you get the basic skeleton up, it's not that hard to implement.  Also there's a nice guide right here, that tells you how:

http://blogs.msdn.com/adamroot/pages/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx

Comment: There should be no COM interop necessary to support drag-drop within the application, AFAIK (note *"onto another control (picture of trash can)"*.

Comment: Wow @Cheeso - that definitely looks complex - might be useful later for more advanced visuals.

Comment: Ahh, Fredrik, you are correct!! I mis-interpreted the question. The COM interop is necessary only when doing shell-integrated Drag/drop. My bad.  I've updated the post with a note on that.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [`DragEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx), [`DragLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave.aspx), and [`DragDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx). Also see example, [Implementing Drag and Drop in ListView Controls](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/skulkarni/ImlementingDragandDropinListViewControls11252005035642AM/ImlementingDragandDropinListViewControls.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @KMan the MSDN links are helpful.